# Stream created using StreamController and await for

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am learning stream in dart.
The following code shows a generator method(`countStream`) and a method that uses the stream(`sumStream`), they are from sample code from [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams). It works, meaning that
I can see the following output at the end.

```
end of for
total = 15
```

However, when I try to create a stream using `makeCounter` where I use `StreamController` to create a stream instead of generator (`async* and yield`), I can see the following output.

```
add
add
add
add
add
```

I suppose that `makeCounter` works because I see five "add".
How to fix this problem? Or It may impossible to create a stream with StreamController with `await for`.

```
Future<int> sumStream(Stream<int> stream) async {
  var sum = 0;
  await for (final value in stream) {
    sum += value;
  }

  print("end of for");
  return sum;
}

Stream<int> makeCounter(int to) {
  var controller = StreamController<int>();
  int counter = 0;
  void tick(Timer timer) {
    counter++;
    print("add");
    controller.add(counter);
    if (counter >= to) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
  }

  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), tick);
  return controller.stream;
}

Stream<int> countStream(int to) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}

void test() async {
  var stream = countStream(5);
  //var stream = makeCounter(5); // this does not work correctly
  var sum = await sumStream(stream);
  print("total = $sum");
}
```

Comment: `makeCounter` never closes the returned `Stream` with `controller.close()`, so anything listening to the `Stream` will continue waiting for future events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, It works by adding controller.close() after timer.cancel() in makeCounter